# Ci sono dizionari per i dialetti Italiani?

Tags: translation

Sono italo-americano e sto imparando l'italiano standard. Ho una comprensione decente della lingua e riesco a parlare con i miei genitori. Però alcuni miei parenti siciliani parlano solo in dialetto, e non li capisco.

Ci sono dizionari tra l'italiano standard ed uno qualsiasi dei molti dialetti italiani? (siciliano, napoletano, o altri).

Comment: Un appunto - l'italiano standard non e' equivalente al dialetto toscano: anche se l'italiano e' basato sul dialetto fiorentino antico, quel dialetto e' poi cambiato abbastanza nel corso del tempo da essere ora abbastanza diverso. Per esempio, in molti dialetti toscani la C dura tra due vocali non si pronuncia piú /k/ ma /h/; questo non e' corretto in italiano standard.

Comment: Grazie, lo cambierò

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esistono dei dizionari dei dialetti italiani, pero':

1. quelli di buona qualita' (come [questo](http://www.csfls.it/res/edizioni/catalogo/vocabolario-siciliano/) per il siciliano) spesso non sono disponibili su Internet
2. spesso sono solo `dialetto -> italiano`, e non `italiano -> dialetto`.
3. quelli disponibili su internet sono spesso di dubbia affidabilita'.

Un'alternativa e' **Wiktionary**, un dizionario multilingue che segue un progetto simile a Wikipedia. [Quello in lingua inglese](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Main_Page) e' di gran lunga il piú ricco; vi trovi:

- parole in siciliano con una traduzione in inglese (per esempio, [arricriari](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/arricriari))
- parole in inglese con una traduzione in moltissime lingue, spesso anche il siciliano (per esempio, nel paragrafo Translations della voce [wife](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wife) trovi *"Sicilian: mugghieri (scn) f"* e *"Neapolitan: mugliera f"*

Io in generale mi trovo molto bene con Wiktionary, ma ovviamente valgono le stesse avvertenze che con Wikipedia - non e' necessariamente curato da esperti.

(In Italia usiamo la parola "dialetto" in modo piuttosto ampio - non e' una corretta traduzione dell'inglese "dialect", secondo me. Tra l'italiano e i dialetti non ci sono solo piccole differenze di accento e di lessico: ci sono anche differenze grammaticali - per esempio, in napoletano il genere delle parole non si segnala con la vocale finale, bensí con un cambiamento della vocale interna e con un raddoppiamento della consonante iniziale. Secondo me imparare un dialetto dell'italiano per chi conosce l'italiano e' un po' come imparare il portoghese conoscendo lo spagnolo...)